# How to remove the inline references in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, codelens

Good day

I am looking to remove the inline references in my code as it clutters the code and provides no functionality that I need.

I have tried going to: Tools, Options, Text Editor, All Languages, CodeLens and disabling code lens, but the references remain in the code. They have not gone away.

How do I get the references to go away completely.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++ (VisualGDB)->CodeJumps

Here set everything to false or 0 (zero). This worked for me.

Finally code that one can read!